Granting Permissions To as User in Mysql
I created user-a that has the following grant privileges
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user-a'@'%';
'GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER, CREATE ROLE, DROP ROLE ON *.* TO `user-a`@`%`'

There's another user, user-b. I am trying to grant it CRUD privileges like so -
GRANT INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE  ON *.* TO 'user-b'@'%';

This throws an access denied error -
Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'user-a'@'%' (using password: YES)

What am I missing? I am using MYSQL version 8.0.35 running on aws rds

You're doing the second GRANT as user-a? You didn't use WITH GRANT OPTION in their grants, so they can't pass on their privileges.

GRANT Statement
